# Does some of the Keras pre-trained networks need particular pre-processing before being used?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Hi everybody I have this basic question that isn't related to any particular piece of code

I'm following some papers about the use of CNN to assess the quality of images and, in all of them, the networks that are being used are the ones offered by keras-applications (VGG16-19, ResNet..) with some variations depanding on the paper

Often, in these works, the variations to the basic networks aren't bound to them but valid for the whole paper, meaning the only differences should be the images input size and the specific image pre-processing function, the latters also provided within keras-application."basic network name"

My question is if what I'm doing is sufficient because, in fact, when I try to replicate the results of a paper, there are some networks that underperform (the results aren't that bad, meaning the network is still training in the right direction) compared to the expected results but others don't. In particular, I had problems with ResNet50 and VGG16 but not with MobileNet v1/v2 and InceptionV3: no matter how much learning rate (or even the dropouts) I use, the validation loss obtained at the end of the trainings are almost 10% worse to the published results when using ResNet or VGG

I'm sure the code is correct, as I said the only difference when changing the loaded basic network is which image pre-processing function is selected. At this point I have two possible ideas:

1. I'm using a different setup compared to the papers (tensorflow 1.15) and the Keras-applications has some kind of bug. In fact the last published version of that module has some bugs regarding the pre-processing in that the code threw an exception when I tried it for the first time. By digging on their Git page I found that that problem was endeed a bug that had already been fixed within the last **commit** (not yet published inside a proper release). Sadly, that doesn't mean its behaviour isn't bugged but I can't verify that by myself
2. Some networks, such as VGG16 and ResNet50, have more requirements to work properly and I'm missing them, what can you tell me from your experience? Have you found yourself in a situation like mine? Note that I'm not talking about parameters such as the dropouts, learning rates etc.. because they are provided by the papers, I'm wondering if for example the function, and relative interpolation, used to load the images could matter in any kind of way

Comment: Which dataset do you use for training and validation?

Comment: I'm using AVA with the common split for training and validation

Comment: That is the probably the main reason you can't replicate the results; most papers use ImageNet for training and validation.

Comment: No the papers I'm looking at are all using AVA because of the scores format

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal You should not assume that all papers are evaluated on ImageNet